# Swift defer function doesn't seem to work with textField delegate shouldChangeCharactersIn

Tags: ios, swift

I'm running this code

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    //does stuff
    defer {
        moveResponder(textField) // this assigns a new first responder after the character is input
    }
    return true
```

Defer is supposed to run after the function ends. However, when I run this code the responder does indeed get moved to a new one and then the character change is implemented. I want it to be moved after the character is changed but the defer statement isn't working here as intended. Am I missing something with this or do I need to try something else?

Comment: Maybe, instead, do it "later" - ie `DispatchQueue.main.async {...}` so you can remove yourself from the current call hierarchy

Comment: You need to resign the current first responder then make something else first responder.. try calling `endEditing(forced: true)`

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.async {} worked wonderfully thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Actually [`defer`](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#ID532) executes just *before* exiting the function… from the doc's

> A defer statement is used for executing code just before transferring program control outside of the scope that the defer statement appears in.

So, when you combine that with the `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)` which is simply asking if the change **should** be allowed, it makes sense that the move occurs before the change is committed.

If your conditions are met you should call `textField.resignFirstResponder()` then you can listen for the delegate method to call your function:

```
optional func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    moveResponder(textField)
}
```